Count by previous method output
I would like to group and count the previous method's results.
I have this query:
count by (url) (count_over_time({app="myapp"} | logfmt [$__range]))

Returns in Grafana the following:



url
Value #A




A
2


B
1


C
3


D
1


E
1


F
3



Now I want to count the Value #A, but how can I refer to that values (what's the label of it)?
count by ([what I put here?]) (count by (url) (count_over_time({app="myapp"} | logfmt [$__range])))

I want to get (something like this):



Value #A
Value #A 2




1
3


2
1


3
2



Ideally, I want to do it with the query instead of Grafana's "transform".
